# How does AuthMe block actions in Minecraft prior to authentication?

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to make a plugin similar to AuthMe, blocking all actions - placing/breaking blocks, altering inventory, chatting - when a player just joined until he logs in with a command.

The reason I don't want to use AuthMe is because I want it to communicate with my website, like using the same password as the accounts on the site.

Answer (score 7):

Create a [`Listener`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/Listener.html) that listens to all the events you want to cancel.

Look at the different packages under [`org.bukkit.event`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/package-frame.html).
You will probably need to hook into most of [`org.bukkit.event.player`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/player/package-frame.html) events.

I suggest you take a look at [AuthMe Reloaded](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/authme-reloaded/) source code to figure out how it does it.
Check out the [`fr.xephi.authme.listener`](https://github.com/Xephi/AuthMeReloaded/tree/master/src/main/java/fr/xephi/authme/listener) package.

Answer (score 1):

I can provide you with some code to do this as I have wrote AuthMC copies myself.

First you'll need to make a list of the events that need cancelling. Then you'll need a HashSet of 'logged in' players. Each event listener will check if a player is in a HashSet and cancel the event if they are not.

```
HashSet<String> loggedInPlayers = new HashSet<String>();

public void blockBreak(BlockBreakEvent e) {
    if(!logginInPlayers.contains(e.getPlayer().getName()) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

Note that the HashSet should contain the players name. This is to save memory as storing the Player directly will take up a LOT of memory as you should well know.

You'll also need an Event Listener that removes players from the HashSet when they log out.

```
public void playerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent e) {
    loggedInPlayers.remove(e.getPlayer().getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As people have said before, all you must do is listen for the event to occur and check if they are on a specified list. Not necessarily a List, a HashMap would work as well. As would a HashSet, as has been suggested. However, getting it to connect to your site will be a bit difficult and I can't answer how to do that, as I have no knowledge on the subject.

An example of cancelling an event for when a player chats (I use it in my own plugin, and I use a HashSet to tell if a player is logged on or not):

```
HashSet<String> loggedIn = new HashSet<String>();

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {
  if (!loggedIn.contains(event.getPlayer().getName()) {
    event.setCancelled(true);
    event.getPlayer().sendMessage("You must log in to chat!"); //Optional
  }
}
```

You would also want something to remove them from the list of players that are logged in when they quit:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event) {
    loggedIn.remove(event.getPlayer().getName());
}
```

Just repeat the example I gave for chat for other events and you are all set!